# Error while executing stored procedure

Tags: oracle

Im getting below error in Oracle while executing below stored procedure. Could you please let me know what is the error.

```
[Error] Syntax check (5: 22): ERROR line 5, col 22, ending_line 5, ending_col 22, Found 'TABLE', Expecting: ;   -or-   :=   -or-   .   -or-   @   -or-   (  ROW

PROCEDURE MyProcedure(res OUT NUMBER)
 AS
      is_output    BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
 TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable;

END MyProcedure;
```

Comment: If I replace "Truncate" with "delete", it is executed without any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` is a DDL statement, so you need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` when calling it from pl/sql..

```
PROCEDURE MyProcedure(res OUT NUMBER)
AS
    is_output    BOOLEAN;
BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE MyTable';

END MyProcedure;
```

Comment: @Srinivasan, just be aware that TRUNCATE, being DDL, issues a COMMIT before and after - unlike DELETE, which is DML.